# I need help closing a DialogDisplayer window in a Netbeans Platform application

Tags: java, netbeans

I am adding to an existing codebase using the Netbeans Platform (14) and its GUI builder to display user selected data to create an output file. The user selects the inputs, then selects to generate the file using a default file name. I want to interrupt the process with a dialog presenting the user with a summary of what they entered, a `TextField` containing the default file name and the OK - Cancel buttons. I created a `DialogDisplayer` configured by a `DialogDescriptor` containing a `JPanel` which contains the summary info and file name `JTextField`. This all works, I see the summary data, am able to modify the file name but selecting the `OK` or `Cancel` doesn't close the window.  Only the X in the upper right will close it.

My `actionPerformed()` method gets called and exercises the code appropriate to the selected button, but just can't figure out how to close the window from there. I tried setting the closing options to null (`dd.setClosingOptions(null);`) which the API says causes all action to close the window. No dice.

I don't see a method to call to close the `DialogDisplayer` window in the API.

I originally thought of using a `JDialog` but it requires a Frame, which I can't figure out how to get from a `org.netbeans.spi.project.ActionProvider`, the enclosing class that initiates the request. I have used Swing for more years than I care to admit (since java 1.1) but the Netbeans Platform framework is new to me.

Here is my code:

```
private class FileNameDialog extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private final JTextField fileNameField = new JTextField(50);
    private final JLabel fileNameLabel = new JLabel("File Name");
    private final JLabel infoLabel = new JLabel();
    private final JPanel entryPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    public FileNameDialog(String fileName, String info)
    {
        infoLabel.setText(info);
        fileNameField.setText(fileName);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        entryPanel.add(fileNameLabel);
        entryPanel.add(fileNameField);
        add(BorderLayout.CENTER, infoLabel);
        add(BorderLayout.PAGE_END, entryPanel);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals(OK_BUTTON))
        {
            //Replace the file name with what was entered and move on
            abort = false;   //Global field in enclosing class
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Setting abort to FALSE for {0}",
                       fileNameField.getText());
        }
        else if (e.getActionCommand().equals(CANCEL_BUTTON))
        {
            abort = true;   //Global field in enclosing class
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Setting abort to TRUE");
        }
        //Close the Dialog Window Here (somehow)
    }
}
/**
 * Request text entry from the user. Currently used for displaying the 
 * file name and allowing the user to update it. This is the entry point
 * for all this code.
 * @param info summary text
 * @param title window title
 * @return the user entered String
 */
private String userRequestDialog(String info, String title, String fileName)
{
    FileNameDialog fileNameDialog = new FileNameDialog(fileName, info);
    
    Object [] options =  {  new JButton ("OK"), 
                            new JButton ("Cancel")};

    DialogDescriptor dd = new DialogDescriptor (fileNameDialog, 
                     title, 
                     true, 
                     options, 
                     null, 
                     DialogDescriptor.DEFAULT_ALIGN, 
                     null, 
                     fileNameDialog);

    DialogDisplayer.getDefault().notify(dd);   //Display the window
    dd.setClosingOptions(null);  //Doesn't seem to have any effect
    return fileNameDialog.fileNameField.getText(); //FileName to use as process continues
}
```

Just for giggles, I tried `Object frame = lookup.lookup(JFrame.class);` but that comes back as null.

Comment: If you switch back to a standard JDialog, you can use Netbeans API WindowManager.getDefault().getMainWindow() to get access to the Netbeans platform main frame.

Answer (score 0):

@jjazzboss - You had the answer that solved my problem and you should get the credit.

Though it technically didn't answer the question, it allowed me to replace the Netbeans DialogDisplayer with a JOptionPane as in below.  I also tried a CustomDialog modeled after the one in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html, but the OK and Cancel buttons still didn't close it.  I suspect that something in Netbeans is stealing those events because a breakpoint in the listener never got hit (or I screwed up the code).

```
    boolean cancelled = false;
    Frame frame = WindowManager.getDefault().getMainWindow();
    while (!cancelled)
    {
        String newFileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, info, fileName);
        if (newFileName == null) //OK was not selected
        {
            return null;
        }
        else if (isValidFileName(newFileName))
        {
            return newFileName;
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    frame,
                    "Sorry, \"" + newFileName + "\" "
                    + "isn't a valid file name.\n"
                    + "Please Try again",
                    "Bad File Name",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }
    }
```